# how to plot value counts plot against threshold in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have two columns in df like this:

```
y = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

x = [0.980, 0.460, 0.393, 0.556, 0.778, 0.663, 0.878, 0.130, 0.224, 0.723]
```

I want to plot the value counts of column 'y' with respect to 'x' in a bar chart form, on the x-axis 'x' and y-axis 'y'. For example : It should shows how many (percent, if possible) values of 'y' fall in the range of 0.200 to 0.600 and so on like a histogramm. I tried plotting dist plot with sns but couldn't plot right. Any idea, how to achieve this?

Comment: `plt.hist(x, bins=[0,0.2,0.6,1])`?

Comment: @QuangHoang how will it shows the percent or value count of y, which falls inside particular range.